# Arrays and variables clears itself after a end sub in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am writing a times tables program in ASP.net and I need some help. The problem I am experiencing is that when the button sub ends and the screen pops up again for user input, all the arrays and variables are now set to nothing or 0.

Is there are way to keep all the values for variables after a sub ends and to use them later on?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Public Class PickTimesTables
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim NumberQ As Integer
    Dim RandomN As Integer
    Dim FirstNumber() As Integer
    Dim FirstNumberTemp() As Integer
    Dim SecondNumber() As Integer
    Dim correctAnswers As Integer
    Dim inc As Integer = 0

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PanelQuestion.Visible = False
        PanelAnalysis.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
        PanelQuestion.Visible = True
        lblOperator.Text = "X"
        If chktimes1.Checked = False And chktimes2.Checked = False And chktimes3.Checked = False And chktimes4.Checked = False And chktimes5.Checked = False And chktimes6.Checked = False And chktimes7.Checked = False And chktimes8.Checked = False And chktimes9.Checked = False And chktimes10.Checked = False And chktimes11.Checked = False And chktimes12.Checked = False Then
            MsgBox("Pick a Times Table to be Tested for..")
        ElseIf txtNoQuestion.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Pick the Number of Question for the test")
        Else
            NumberQ = txtNoQuestion.Text
            count = 0
            If chktimes1.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes2.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes3.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes4.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes5.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes6.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes7.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes8.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes9.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes10.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes11.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
            If chktimes12.Checked Then
                count = count + 1
            End If

            If txtNoQuestion.Text = 0 Then
                MsgBox("You cannot have a test with 0 Questions")
            Else
                ReDim FirstNumberTemp(count - 1)
                For i = 0 To count - 1
                    If chktimes1.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 1
                        chktimes1.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes2.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 2
                        chktimes2.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes3.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 3
                        chktimes3.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes4.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 4
                        chktimes4.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes5.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 5
                        chktimes5.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes6.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 6
                        chktimes6.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes7.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 7
                        chktimes7.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes8.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 8
                        chktimes8.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes9.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 9
                        chktimes9.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes10.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 10
                        chktimes10.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes11.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 11
                        chktimes11.Checked = False
                    ElseIf chktimes12.Checked Then
                        FirstNumberTemp(i) = 12
                        chktimes12.Checked = False
                    End If
                Next
                ReDim FirstNumber(NumberQ - 1)
                For i = 0 To NumberQ - 1
                    Randomize()
                    RandomN = FirstNumberTemp(Int(Rnd() * count))
                    FirstNumber(i) = RandomN
                Next

                ReDim SecondNumber(NumberQ - 1)
                For i = 0 To NumberQ - 1
                    Dim rn As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
                    RandomN = rn.Next(1, 13)
                    SecondNumber(i) = RandomN
                Next

                lblFirstN.Text = FirstNumber(0)
                lblSecondN.Text = SecondNumber(0)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub txtInput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtInput.TextChanged
        NumberQ = txtNoQuestion.Text
        If txtInput.Text = FirstNumber(inc) * SecondNumber(inc) Then
            lblFirstN.Text = FirstNumber(inc + 1)
            lblSecondN.Text = SecondNumber(inc + 1)
            correctAnswers = correctAnswers + 1
            txtInput.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        Else
            txtInput.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblFirstN.Text = FirstNumber(inc + 1)
            lblSecondN.Text = SecondNumber(inc + 1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake for newcomers to ASP.Net Webforms. There is this idea that your page class instance lives for an entire session, for all of a user's interactions with the page in the browser. **This does not happen.** Any interaction with your page that causes an event to fire creates a new postback from the client to the server, and *every postback uses a brand new instance of the Page class*. By the time the user sees your page in their browser, whatever Page object you used to render the html for that view has already been destroyed and garbage collected.

There are some things you can do to get around this, like putting variables in the Session, URL, or ViewState, but often you need to completely re-think your approach to something that is more natural for a web site.

Additionally, you'll want to re-think handling a TextChanged event in your VB.Net code. Generally speaking, TextChanged events need to return to the user in 25-40 milliseconds, or the view will feel extremely sluggish. It's not usually a problem when the program is running right there on the user's computer, and has all the memory and CPU power of that workstation available. It's a whole other story for web sites, where you might have an 80ms delay before the request even reaches the server and another 80ms for the response, all before doing any processing, and the server is sharing it's CPU and memory resources to support as many users as you can fit.

Instead, look into using a javascript event for that processing, and only validate the text in your VB.Net code when the user finally tries to submit or save the end result.

Finally, those calls to the `MsgBox()` function need to go, too. It only seems to work on your system because your web server is on the same machine as the web browser. When you go to actually put this on a real server and test from a different place, those message will display on the server, *not* in the user's web browser.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i'm doing a multiplication program which will allow the user to test their skills , I will need the program to output the first equation and then allow the user to type in the answer. This will then fire the textchanged handler and preform the calculation. Is there another way way of doing this without using the textchanged handler?

Comment: Do that part in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

They'll all be reset because that's the stateless nature of the web. They don't keep their values because each subsequent time you view that page (or step through it using the debugger), it's a new request.

You should google storing asp.net variables in ViewState or Session, i.e. ViewState-backed properties.